# Exceedingly slow django queries comparing two fields

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a setup similar to the following:

```
class TimeFrame(models.Model):
    """A range of dates and times.  On each date in the given range,
        associated objects are available only within the provided time
        range.
    """
    class Meta:
        index_together=(('time_from','time_until'),)

    date_from = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    date_until = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    time_from = models.TimeField(db_index=True)
    time_until = models.TimeField(db_index=True)

    scheduled_model = models.ForeignKey(ScheduledModel)
```

`time_until` can be less than `time_from`, though, which severely complicates the condition.  For example, something may be available from 9 PM to 2 AM.  I've written a filter to find available `TimeFrame`s like so:

```
open_time_frame_filter = (
    Q(
        # Cases like 9pm-2am.
        Q(time_from__gt=F('time_until')),
        Q(
            # Past 9pm.
            time_from__lte=time,
            date_from__lte=date,
            date_until__gte=date
        ) | Q(
            # Before 2am.
            time_until__gte=time,
            date_from__lte=date - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
            date_until__gte=date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        )
    ) | Q(
        # Normal cases.
        Q(time_from__lte=F('time_until')),
        Q(time_from__lte=time),
        Q(time_until__gte=time),
        Q(date_from__lte=date),
        Q(date_until__gte=date)
    )
)
```

`time` and `date` are, predictably, a time and a date.  Unfortunately, something here is quite inefficient, and this ends up being ultimately less efficient than just retrieving all of the `TimeFrame`s that fit and iterating over them in python.  After using ancient tracking methods (commenting things out) to discover the root cause, it seems to be the lines with the `F` objects, where one field is compared with another, that slow down the query.  I need to be able to use a filter here for flexibility, but with the current inefficiency, it's just too slow.  For consistency with the rest of the project, I'd like to stay away from raw SQL.  I'm not really sure where to begin troubleshooting this kind of problem, though.

**EDIT**

`TimeFrame` objects are tied to a separate object via a foreign key on time frame (many-to-one).  The filter is then more accurately described as so:

```
class ScheduledModel(models.Model):
    """A model with an associated schedule (described by several time
        frames).
    """

    @property
    def is_open(self):
        """Is the model currently open?"""
        time = datetime.now().time()
        date = datetime.now().date()
        return TimeFrame.objects.filter(
            Q(scheduled_model_id=self.id),
            open_time_frame_filter # As defined above.
        ).exists()
```

In the manual python version, the query set of time frames is retrieved by id first, then iterated on to determine if any are open.  In principal, this query should do the same and would be faster given that time_from, time_until, date_from, and date_until are indexed and time_from and time_until are indexed together.  There are only around ten time frames for each scheduled models, though there hundreds of thousands of time frames in total.

**EDIT 2**

I've corrected the original model for clarity on what has been tried.

Comment: Why not use two `DateTimeField` or try to build a SQL view to have such two fields? Otherwise you may need to build multi-column index or expression index on the table.

Comment: I'm not simply checking whether a datetime falls between two datetimes, but rather whether a time falls between two times and a date falls between two dates independently.  Indexing `time_from` and `time_until` together didn't occur to me.  I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: Indexing these together didn't decrease the query time at all, so I've switched back to retrieving the relevant `TimeFrame`s and iterating over them in python to determine which are open.

Comment: Hmm, what are the typical count of matched and all DB rows or could you even provide some sample dataset for emulation?

Comment: That's part of my confusion here.  I've made an edit to explain some additional complexity that may arise.

Comment: Providing a sample dataset would be difficult considering the performance concerns only become apparent at scale.